# Bokeh, how do I add the "?" in the configuring plot tool

Tags: bokeh

I could not find the information regarding the helptool on the bokeh documentation. There is an explanation for all other tools but not this one. I am talking about these tools from the toolbar:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html

[image: Bokekh plot tools]

I can choose most of the plot tools I want to use with no problem. I want to include the helptool, which is clearly visible just before the bokeh logo, however I cannot find any direct reference to it. 
I just tested it(!), if you want the Helptool, which has a "?" sybmol, it will only be included by default if you do not specify the tools displayed with the plot. OK I will go with this but I will have no "?" if I choose the tools.

Comment: Can you add some more details around the issue and what you are trying to achieve. This is too vague.

Comment: OhOh just tested it more and I found a bug in bokeh. I cannot use the the solution above to get the "?" I am going to report it and create the code for the bokeh people to test it.

Comment: And the last comment, if you don't configure the toolbar in figure() you will get the "?" but if you pick your tools then the "?" disappears. This give the answer to the question. Sometimes just by asking it helps. Thank you Anthony

Comment: Not a problem, There is a way to achieve what you want - see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your problem I think. You are saying that by default the tool panel will include the help tool. When you specify all the tools from scratch, help tool is not included as default.

If you generate the plot without specifying any tools, then list all tools on the plot:

```
p.tools
>>>>
[PanTool(id='450f2e26-e0e5-4d90-89c4-44d20f2f688b', ...),
 WheelZoomTool(id='84011ce1-4f73-4abb-abd1-26a830b70635', ...),
 BoxZoomTool(id='adbfb29a-aa7d-4883-8f8f-d12b7c5af139', ...),
 SaveTool(id='ff6ba8bb-c487-418d-82e5-28ff0402e2d6', ...),
 ResetTool(id='dfac2559-da4c-4902-829d-f795ee0bfd56', ...),
 HelpTool(id='1141330c-e9ff-4e5b-a737-3517c24f263e', ...)]
```

so you can see there is a helptool. Also it is in the documents 
http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.tools.HelpTool

Therefore you can import this tool and add it to the plot in two ways:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import HelpTool

output_file("toolbar.html")

# create a new plot with the toolbar below
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
           title=None, toolbar_location="below", tools="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset")
p.add_tools(HelpTool())

p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 5, 8, 2, 7], size=10)

show(p)
```

Or more simply:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("toolbar.html")

# create a new plot with the toolbar below
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
           title=None, toolbar_location="right",tools = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,help")

p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 5, 8, 2, 7], size=10)

show(p)
```

Comment: This worked. When you look at it you will think that by having no configured toolbar you will have the same result, which mean it will show you all the tools. Yes if you have no Hovertool configured. I have 4 hover tools and when I did not configured the toolbar the Helptool then muted one of the Hovertool. Configuring the toolbar with Help did not mute the the last Hovertool.